# OllyDbg - After restarting program, breakpoints lost

Tags: debugging, ollydbg, debuggers

I am new to OllyDbg and I made a small (.NET Console App) program to test if I can crack the password. To set the break point where it writes **Incorrect password.** I need to run the program first. But after it prints the password is incorrect, it closes, and when I click Debug>Restart it deletes the break point.

So, how can I fix this?

I am using OllyDbg 2

Comment: Which language is your program written in?

Comment: It is written in C#

Comment: Olly will fail with analysis of C# programs. It's because it supports x86 architecture, while C# program is compiled to Common Intermediate Language which is not x86 assembly. You can rewrite it in C++ an everything should be fine. See https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21465/ascii-strings-not-showing-up-in-cpu-in-ollydbg-but-rather-in-dump/21517#21517

Comment: So do you think using e.g VB.NET (I hate that but.. That's the only programming language I can code in a bit in Visual Studio) will fix the problem?
I think I'll try C++

Comment: No, it's also compiled to intermediate language. But you may use some other debugger.

Comment: So I can't do it in OllyDBG 2? Maybe x32dbg/x64dbg? EDIT: It is not working, same thing, removing the break points. So I need to do it in other language and also with another debugger?

Comment: If you write it in C++, both Olly and x64dbg will work. For C#, VB.NET you will need another debugger.

Comment: So, if I write it in C++, Ollydbg and x64dbg will keep the break points?

Comment: Yes, they will work as you expect.

Comment: ProgRAMmer - If you are reversing/debugging a .NET executable, I highly recommend dnSpy's debugger - it works really well for this purpose and is about as good as VS's own debugger.

Comment: Now the debuggers can't find the `Incorrect password.` string. I am using `Alt + M` (Memory map) and then Ctrl + B to search, it cant find
EDIT: also the code is just `std::cout << "Incorrect password.";`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not related to Reverse Engineering, but rather the use of OllyDbg.

Comment: yeah u vote to close this but I can't find a normal answer for my question.. And thats a bigger problem than closing just one question